# Evaluate $\int _0^1\:\int _{\sqrt{1-x²}}^{\sqrt{5-x²}}\:xdydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If I want to calculate with values ​​to two decimal places and maybe pi,
$$\int _0^1\:\int _{\sqrt{1-x²}}^{\sqrt{5-x²}}\:xdydx$$
$$\int _0^1\:(x\sqrt{5-x²}-x\sqrt{1-x²})dx$$
$$=\frac{5\sqrt{5}-8}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$=\frac{5.2,23 -8}{3}-0,33$$
$$=\frac{11,15 -8}{3}-0,33$$
$$=1,05-0,33=0,72$$
It's correct?

Comment: What would a resolution having pi look like?

Comment: It is correct. If you round it to two decimal, it should in fact be $0.73$. What do you mean a resolution using $\pi$? You have an integrand $x$ so there is no $\pi$ in the answer.

Comment: I thought I would have a resolution that would result in some pi, can you tell me where I went wrong with the rounding? Because you said you have to give 0.73

Comment: instead of writing $1/3$ as $0.33$, first note that your answer is $ (5 \sqrt5 - 9) / 3 \approx (11.18 - 9) / 3 = 2.18 / 3 = 0.7266......$

Comment: but where you put 9 would actually be 8

Comment: $ \displaystyle \frac{5 \sqrt5 - 8}{3} - \frac 13 = \frac{5 \sqrt5 - 9}{3}$

Comment: oh sorry, that's right